# How to fix xml document data by retireving xpaths

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'd like to get the XPaths for an XML document which has repeating elements.

**Example:**

```
<Return>
  <ReturnData>
    <Person>
      <Name>Yohanna</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Jacoub</Name>
    </Person>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

I'd like to get returned me:

```
1. /Return/ReturnData/Person[1]/Name=Yohanna
2. /Return/ReturnData/Person[2]/Name=Jacoub
```

I have got an implementation which retrieves me the XPaths for any XML document however I have the problem of repeating XPaths where I am unsure how to index the XPaths to be unique so I can assign values to it in as `Key/Value` pairs as I showed above. I suppose I should use ***Map*** data structure but I am unsure how to do this.

***Here is my code***:

```
public List<String> getXPaths ( InputStream stream ) throws ParserException {
    Document document = XMLUtils.getDocument(  stream );
    return getXPaths( document.getDocumentElement() );
}

public List<String> getXPaths ( Node node ) {
    List<String> xpaths = iterate( node, "");
    return xpaths;
}


public List<String> iterate ( Node node, String parentPath )  {

    List<String> xpaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {

        Element element = ( Element ) node;
        parentPath = parentPath + "/" +  element.getTagName();

        for ( int nIndex = 0; nIndex<node.getChildNodes().getLength(); nIndex++ ) {
            xpaths.addAll( iterate(node.getChildNodes().item(nIndex) , parentPath ) ) ;
        }
    }
    else if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ) {
        if (  node.getTextContent().trim().length() !=0 ) {
            logger.debug("XPath found : " + parentPath );
            xpaths.add( parentPath );
        }
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("Unknown node type for : " + node.getNodeName());
    }
    return xpaths;
}
```

Currently this code returns me only a ***list of XPaths not indexed***:

***Output:***

```
/Return/ReturnData/Person/Name
/Return/ReturnData/Person/Name
```

***Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.***

**Another edit:**

```
public String getFullXPathV2(Node n) {
    ...etc.

            while (null != prev_sibling) {

                if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
                    if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) { 
                        prev_siblings++;
                    }
                }
                prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();
            }

            // Edit here
            if(prev_siblings == 1) {
                continue;
            } 

            else 
                builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");

        } 

        else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
            builder.append("/@");
            builder.append(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

output:

```
[/Return/ReturnData/Person/Name = Yohanna, /Return/ReturnData/Person[2]/Name = Jacoub]
```

This seems okay but /Return/ReturnData/Person/Name = Yohanna it should be /Person[1] to signify its the first occurance of Person node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have xpath values after your code executes. You have to evaluate your xpath expressions for getting exact indexes and values from this xpathes.

You can save it to file or collection and process it later. I will show some example when all your xpathes without indexes are saved to file. And this file will be processed.

Code should be smt as follows:

```
public final class XpathEvaluator {
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private Document document;

    public XpathEvaluator() {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Logger.error("Can not create document builder for xpath ", e.getCause());
        }
    }

    public void loadFile(String filename) {
        Logger.operation("Load file for Xpath evaluation: " + filename);
        File file = new File(filename);
        try {
            document = builder.parse(file);
        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
            Logger.error("exception at loading xml file", e.getCause());
        }
    }

    public List<NodeSearchResult> getXpathSearchResults(String xpathExpression) {
        Logger.operation("Evaluate xpath expression: [" + xpathExpression + "]");
        List<NodeSearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

        XPathExpression expression;
        NodeList list = null;
        try {
            expression = getXPath().compile(xpathExpression);
            list = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            Logger.error("XPathExpressionException during xpath evaluation", e.getCause());
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < list.getLength(); index++) {
            Node node = list.item(index);
            String nodeXPath = getFullXPath(node);
            String content = node.getTextContent();

            Logger.debug("Get NODE value: [" + content + "]");
            results.add(new NodeSearchResult(nodeXPath, content));
        }

        if (results.isEmpty()) { // log error if node result is empty
            Logger.warn("XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [" + xpathExpression + "]");
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        Logger.operation("Xpath evaluation results: " + results);
        return results;
    }

    private String getFullXPath(Node n) {
        if (null == n)
            return null;

        Node parent;
        Stack<Node> hierarchy = new Stack<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        hierarchy.push(n);

        switch (n.getNodeType()) {
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
                parent = ((Attr) n).getOwnerElement();
                break;
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                parent = n.getParentNode();
                break;
            case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
                parent = n.getParentNode();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected Node type" + n.getNodeType());
        }

        while (null != parent
                && parent.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE
                && !parent.getNodeName().equals("section")) {
            hierarchy.push(parent);
            parent = parent.getParentNode();
        }

        Object obj;
        while (!hierarchy.isEmpty() && null != (obj = hierarchy.pop())) {
            Node node = (Node) obj;

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                builder.append("/").append(node.getNodeName());

                int prev_siblings = 1;
                Node prev_sibling = node.getPreviousSibling();

                while (null != prev_sibling) {
                    if (prev_sibling.getNodeType() == node.getNodeType()) {
                        if (prev_sibling.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
                            prev_siblings++;
                        }
                    }
                    prev_sibling = prev_sibling.getPreviousSibling();
                }
                builder.append("[").append(prev_siblings).append("]");
            } else if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
                builder.append("/@");
                builder.append(node.getNodeName());
            }
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private XPath getXPath() {
        XPathFactory pathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        return pathFactory.newXPath();
    }
```

For Xpath results better to create separate ***POJO*** class:

```
public class NodeSearchResult {
    private String xPath;
    private String value;

    public NodeSearchResult(String xPath, String value) {
        this.xPath = xPath;
        this.value = value;
    }
    // getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s = %s", getXPath(), getValue());
    }
}
```

Your main should looks something as follows:

```
    List<List<NodeSearchResult>> xpathResultsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<NodeSearchResult> searchResults;
    List<CSVDataLine> inputData = getCSVInputData();

    for (CSVDataLine anInputData : inputData) {
        String inputXPath = anInputData.getXPath();
        searchResults = xpathEvaluator.getXpathSearchResults(inputXPath);
        xpathResultsList.add(searchResults);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to do this task. `input.xml` is your xml snippet file. I created mock for your extraction not indexed xpaths. If you don't need to save xpaths for future usage omit saving to file. Just save to list and process it later.

Here is my ***main***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> inputXpaths = new ArrayList<>();
    inputXpaths.add("/Return/ReturnData/Person/Name");

    XpathEvaluator evaluator = new XpathEvaluator();
    evaluator.loadFile("src/test/resources/xml/input.xml");
    List<NodeSearchResult> xpathSearchResults = evaluator.getXpathSearchResults(inputXpaths.get(0));
    System.out.println(xpathSearchResults);
}
```

***Output:***

```
2015-08-25 08:07:59 [main] INFO - OPERATION - Load file for Xpath evaluation: src/test/resources/xml/input.xml
2015-08-25 08:07:59 [main] INFO - OPERATION - Evaluate xpath expression: [/Return/ReturnData/Person/Name]
2015-08-25 08:07:59 [main] INFO - OPERATION - Xpath evaluation results: [/Return[1]/ReturnData[1]/Person[1]/Name[1] = Yohanna, /Return[1]/ReturnData[1]/Person[2]/Name[1] = Jacoub]
[/Return[1]/ReturnData[1]/Person[1]/Name[1] = Yohanna, /Return[1]/ReturnData[1]/Person[2]/Name[1] = Jacoub]
```

Your trouble was that you hadn't loaded xml file for `xpathEvaluator`. It doesn't know from which file to evaluate xpathes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, while I study your code, what import libraries are you using?

Comment: @mosawi I am using standard java API. If you have installed JDK you'd not have any troubles. `Logger` is custom implementation for Log4j just replace with `System.out` and `StringUtils`  has one method for appending strings, you can easily replace it with `String.format()`.

Comment: You're code implementation is very nice, I'm still going through to understand this. Very nicely done

Comment: I'm slightly confused as what List<CSVDataLine> inputData = getCSVInputData(); is? The data I have is an XML file could I just use File f = new File("path/to/xml/file.xml"); but this wouldn't be a list? I guess I just am unsure how to use your class XpathEvaluator

Comment: @mosavi It is csv file with extracted Xpaths without indexes. You able to replase it with `ArrayList`. Just save all "unindexed" Xpathes to list => process this list through foreach and evaluate through XpathEvaluator for every unindexed xpath => collect extracted results to NodeSearchResult list.

Comment: how can I make the output as [/Return/ReturnData/Person[1]/Name = Yohanna, /Return/ReturnData/Person[2]/Name = Jacoub] so the index is only occurs for nodes who have mulitple occurances and not the nodes who only have single occurances? I've tried editing getFullXpath but to no avail. I've edited my original question to show my edit