# Getting Empty values for XML file with has values

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'd like to get the XPaths and values for an XML document which has repeating elements.

**Example:**

```
<Return>
  <ReturnData>
    <Person>
      <Name>Yohanna</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Jacoub</Name>
    </Person>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

I'd like to get returned me:

```
1. /Return/ReturnData/Person[1]/Name=Yohanna
2. /Return/ReturnData/Person[2]/Name=Jacoub
```

I previously had a different implementation of my Java code but got this implementation from someone else(@nazar_art). However when I go to retrieve Xpaths and values from my top level, all the values are returned as blank/empty.

Outer first loop:

```
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/SSN]
2015-08-24 16:10:19,646 : XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/SSN]
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/IsStatutory]
2015-08-24 16:10:19,646 : XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/IsStatutory]
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/HasPensionPlan]
2015-08-24 16:10:19,647 : XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/HasPensionPlan]
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/EmployeeType]
2015-08-24 16:10:19,647 : XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/EmpSummary/EmployeeType]
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/FederalReturnType]
2015-08-24 16:10:19,648 : XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [/PayrollFormInfo/CompanyInfo/FederalReturnType]
Evaluate xpath expression: [/PayrollFormInfo/EmployeeInfo/EmployeeType]
```

Output of 2nd for loop:

```
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
Here! []
```

I don't understand what is wrong? Why can't it find values for the elements when the elements clearly have values.

Here is the XML file being evaluated:

Comment: Linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189039/how-to-get-indexed-xpaths-for-any-xml-document?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Perhaps the Xpaths I am feeding it are incorrect?

Comment: Oh crap, just noticed I'm not loading the document...will report back results

Comment: Yes! It works! Made a silly mistake of not loading the xml document, ofcourse it was empty since there was no xml to read from. Whoops...this is sort of a duplicate question will truncate and move back to original